# Docker can't load config file, but container works fine

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm using docker-machine with [generic driver](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/) to deploy containers on an existing remote host. But when I switch to the remote host and try to run a container, this happens:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address=$REMOTEIP \
--generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa --generic-ssh-user $REMOTEUSER vm
[works fine]

$ eval $(docker-machine env vm) #switch to remote host
[works fine]

$ docker run -it busybox sh
WARNING: Error loading config file:/home/user/.docker/config.json - open /home/user/.docker/config.json: permission denied
[Even with the warning, runs fine]
```

The container runs fine anyway, but I want to solve that warning message.

Given that `user` doesn't exist in the remote host, I guess that this file doesn't exist. But ..

1) why does the engine search for it in the first place? shouldn't it search for the config.json of `$REMOTEUSER` instead of that?

2) and why the container runs properly on the remote host anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is not searching for that file in the remote host but in the local host. Turns out that file exists and it's owned by root.

```
$ ls -lsa ~/.docker/config.json  4 -rw------- 1 root root \
95 dic 29 15:29 /home/user/.docker/config.json
```

That's why it says `permission denied`.

A simple chown fixes the issue:

```
$ sudo chown user:user /home/user/.docker -R
```